# What's the love story in Twilight?

Tags: twilight, love

I see a lot of those memes and images of eg. two kittens, or Spongebob with caption

> still better love story than Twilight

I'm unfortunately not familiar with Twilight. What's the love story of Twilight, and why are there so many of those memes?

If this question is too broad to answer, feel free to delete it.

Comment: This is a general reference question. If you [Google](http://lmgtfy.com/) "Twilight", you will immediately pull up multiple websites that provide plot synopses for all of the *Twilight* books and movies.

Comment: Voted to close as this doesn't cover any Sci-fi aspect. It's better suited to Literary or TV/Movie SE.

Comment: VTC - General Reference

Answer (score 6):

*Twilight*'s portrayal of relationships range from absurd to creepy to pedagogically dangerous. [Film Crit Hulk](http://badassdigest.com/2011/11/17/film-crit-hulk-smash-hulk-vs-twilight/) has done a long article that explains what's going on in the text and subtext, particularly what's wrong with how the story portrays "love" and relationships.

Some choice bits:

> THIS STATEMENT IS PARAPHRASED FROM NOW FAMOUS QUOTE BY STEPHEN KING:"Harry Potter is about confronting fears, finding inner strength and doing what is right in the face of adversity. Twilight is about how important it is to have a boyfriend."
>
> WHILE THAT MAY SEEM DISMISSIVE, HE IS EXACTLY CORRECT. THERE IS USUALLY A FINE LINE BETWEEN THINGS DONE IN THE  REAL LOVE AND THINGS DONE OUT OF THE NAME OF MISGUIDED LOVE.
>
> SO LET'S JUST SAY IT. TWILIGHT IS NOT ABOUT LOVE.
>
> TWILIGHT IS ABOUT INFATUATION.
>
> BECAUSE BELLA CONSTANTLY FORGOES EVERYTHING THAT IS GOOD FOR HER, HER SAFETY, HER FAMILY, HER FRIENDS, HER SCHOOLWORK, HER LIFE, ALL IN THE NAME OF HER UNDYING AND PROFOUND LOVE FOR HER MEAN AND BIPOLAR HIGH SCHOOL BOYFRIEND. THEN HE DUMPS HER SO SHE TRIES TO KILL HERSELF BECAUSE SHE JUST KNOWS THEY'RE MEANT TO BE. FRIENDS AND ADULTS WARN HER, BUT SHE JUST THINKS THEY'RE WRONG. AND GUESS WHAT? MEYER MAKES IT CLEAR THEY ARE WRONG.
>
> ...
>
> THE OVERWHELMING AND CONSTANT PURSUIT OF INFATUATION AND DREAMINESS IS PURSUED WITH NOTHING BUT UTTER DISREGARD FOR ANY KIND OF MATURITY OR PERSONAL INTEGRITY. IT DOES NOTHING BUT PROPELS YOU, THE READER, TOWARD WANTING TO HAVE SUPER AMOUNTS OF SEX WITH A DREAMY EDWARD AND/OR JACOB. HULK HAS PERSONALLY WATCHED TWILIGHT ACCELERATE THE LIBIDO OF MANY YOUNG STUDENTS, ALL TRYING THEY FIND THEIR VERSION OF EDWARD CULLEN. ON A CULTURAL LEVEL, THERE IS A KIND OF THINKING THAT JUST EQUATES EDWARD CULLEN WITH WHAT EVER TEEN HEARTTHROB DU JOUR BUT THE SEXUALITY IN TWILIGHT IS SOMETHING DIFFERENT.
>
> IT IS, QUITE LITERALLY, STEPHENIE MEYER'S MASTURBATORY WET DREAM. AND BECAUSE OF THAT, THE ONLY THING STOPPING THESE CHARACTERS FROM EITHER FUCKIN' OR TURNING VAMPIRE IS EDWARDS'S STEADFAST COMMITMENT TO NOT DOING BOTH, DESPITE THEIR CONSTANT REFRAIN OF  ZOMG WE WANT TO DO IT BOTH SO BADLY. ONCE AGAIN, IT'S NOT LIKE MEYER IS PURPOSEFULLY CHARACTERIZING TEEN BEHAVIOR TO MAKE SOME KIND OF COMMENTARY, SHE IS SIMPLY EXHIBITING A SIMILAR TEENAGE / INFATUATION-LIKE BEHAVIOR.

It's a long article, but covers a lot of ground both emotionally and critically.

Comment: Why is the whole article written with Caps Lock?

Comment: @Thecafremo: Hulk writes like Hulk talks.

Comment: Fair Enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

I very quickly read the first two or three volumes last year, so this is not the opinion of someone who's thought a lot about the books...

There are two things that those memes are poking fun at:

- The main love story in the books is [extremely schmaltzy.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/schmaltzy)  While the definition given in the link is accurate ("excessively sentimental"), one of the thesaurus entries is much better: "mushy effusiveness"
- A significant percentage of the pages in each book is spent describing the feelings of the main characters towards each other.  There is plot, some of it quite entertaining, but it rarely gets in the way of the characters' emotions.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are referring to how there is nothing that should hold these two people together, and I think it is coming from the movies more than the books.  In the movies she is presented as a mopey, quiet, plain-looking, uninteresting girl, and he is  presented as one of the most beautiful people in the town.  The book does a better job of telling the reader what each character is thinking, but the movie leaves the watcher a little less informed.  So the "better love story" meme comes from having this total stud go after the social pariah with nothing to back up the love.

Also, the scene where they meet and are supposed to be acting like they have uncontrollable urges for the other person, it just looks like Kristen Stewart is trying really hard not to throw up.